# Deleting "project" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I have a question whether we should remove [project](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project) tag.

Actually I don't see what value the tag adds. As we discuss project management vast majority of questions could be tagged [project](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project). If there's any value in the tag that I don't see I'd like to hear about this. Otherwise I think it would be a good idea to remove it.

What do you think?

Comment: Both the project and projects tags have been removed. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like the "project" tag is so generic that it dangerously flirts with the boundary of meta-tags. Additionally, I agree that it could theoretically apply to almost all of the questions, since they relate to projects.

I believe the "project" tag should be removed.